# Rails How to get output of url as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**How to get the xml output of a view/controller as string within the same controler**

This is the routes file

routes.rb

```
map.ccda '/ccda/ccda_patient_search', :controller => 'ccda', :action => :ccda_patient_search
map.ccda '/ccda/:id.:format', :controller => 'ccda', :action => :index
```

ccda_controller.rb

```
class CcdaController < ApplicationController
def index    
  # 
  # some process 
  # result = User.find(params[:id]).result
  #
  @ccda = result
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :layout => false, :template=> "index.xml.builder" }
    format.any { redirect_to login_url }
  end   
end

def get_xml
  # render_to_string 'index', :layout=>false, :formats=>[:xml], :locals=>{:id=>147}  => Not working
  # render_to_string '147.xml' => Not working
  #
  # How do I get the output of 'http://localhost/ccda/147.xml' here???
  #
end

end
```

I will use the url `localhost/ccda/147.xml` to view/generate the users result as xml

Now **I want the output of that url as a string without returning to browser**

I've tried to get it from same controller using `render_to_string` method with diffrent parameters but nothing seems to work

FYI: I am using rails 2.3.12 and **Builder::XmlMarkup** API

Comment: Do you have a xml template view already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found that we need to specify the view file manually because by default rails will be looking for `index.erb` so what I've done is this

```
render_to_string( :action=>"index", :view => "/ccda/index.xml.builder",    :format=>:xml,:layout=>false,:id=>146, :template=>"/ccda/index.xml.builder" )
```

specifying `:view` and `:template` manually solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

How about using the following call (inside controller, have taken the known options from your question):

`render_to_string(:template => 'ccda/index.xml.builder', :layout => false, :id => 147)`

Due to the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string), this will work up to Rails version 2.3.8, so I don't know if it is available any more in Rails 2.3.12 you are using.

PS: How about upgrading to at least last version of Rails 3? I don't have a change to test my solution, so it is guesswork more or less.

Comment: it shows `Missing template index.erb in view path` on trying the code and upgrading will take months since it is a huge project

Comment: Changed my answer, but difficult to test (for me).

Comment: No luck, got `Missing template 147.xml in view path`

Comment: Changed again due to the error message. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render for the documentation

Answer (score 0):

How about this below?

```
render_to_string :controller => 'ccda_controller', :action => 'index', :id => 147, :format => :xml
```